# Replace X consecutive repeated zero-values with NA in data frame (R)

Tags: r, na

I have a data frame with a daily value for several users. The users have different start dates, so I have assigned NA for the values before the first use and zero-values for any cells without values thereafter. I have used the following loop to do this:

```
for (i in seq_along(df)) {
 isna <- is.na(df[[i]])
 nonna <- match(FALSE,isna)
 id <- which(isna)
 df[[i]][id[id>nonna]] <- 0
}
```

However, some of the users have a lot of zero-values towards the end, indicating that they have stopped using the service. I would like to set also these values to NA, if there are more than 100 zero-values in the end of the data frame. I have not succeeded in doing this, and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your problem, so let me restate it so you can tell me if I am wrong.

You have a data frame where columns represent users, and rows represent days. Taking a column out of your data frame with `df[[i]]` will therefore give you a time series for one user's activity.

The users didn't all start on the same day, so some of these time series may have a long initial run of `0` activity. This indicates that the user was not yet with your service, and should be `NA` instead of 0. We can therefore assume everything prior to the date of the first non-zero number should be `NA`.

Some users have 0 activity on some days after joining your service. This just means they aren't using your service on that day. However, if they leave your service altogether, they will generate a long run of zeros up to the end of their column from the point at which they left.

Some users might have a few 0s at the end of the data frame by chance - they have not left the service, but just happen not to have used it for a few days at the time point when the data frame stops. These 0s should not be converted to `NA` values. However, if the user has more than 100 consecutive days of zero activity ongoing by the end of their column, all the zeros at the end should be converted to `NA`.

Assuming this is what you mean, and assuming there are no `NA` values to start with in your columns, we can solve the problem with run length encoding. I have commented each line so you can follow the logic:

```r
for(i in length(df))
{
  user <- df[[i]]               # Write the column to a new vector for clarity
  
  MAX      <- 100               # Set the maximum number of 0s allowed at the end
  user_rle <- rle(user)         # Get run length encoding of the column
  lens     <- user_rle$lengths  # Extract the run-length encoding lengths
  vals     <- user_rle$values   # Extract the run-length encoding values
  last     <- length(lens)      # For clarity of code, make alias for last index of rle
  
  if(vals[1] == 0) {            # If zeros at the start...
    user[seq(lens[1])] <- NA    # Replace with NA
  }
  
  if(vals[last] == 0 & lens[last] > MAX) {           # If more than 100 0s at end
    user[(-lens[last] + 1):0 + length(user)] <- NA   # Replace with NA
  }
  
  df[[i]] <- user               # Write the vector back in to the data frame
}
```

Note that there are more efficient ways to do this using less code, but this is intended to be easy to follow.